# Sending value from ui.value (jquery UI) of a slider to #link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

im a jq newbie, but im fighting my way trough ;(

question:

i need to pass a slider variable(ui.value) to a "http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY VALUE_FROM_SLIDER" where value_from_Slider is the value, when i stop sliding.
.

my code can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2AWC/30/

or here:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({                   
            value: 50,
            min: 0,
            max: 99,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#slider_value").val(ui.value);
                      }
    });
    $("#slider_value").val($("#slider").slider("value"));


});
```

html:

```
<div id="slider"></div>    
sliderValue:
```

i know that im missing a new $function, but this is as far as i understand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure wha tyou looking for are you trying to setup the slider based on the value of "http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY VALUE_FROM_SLIDER" where value_from_Slider is the value. Or are you wanting to make a url and place the value for the slider in the url. Please could you explain a bit more to make it clear what you wanting to do.

Comment: i want to put the slider value in the href link and trigger it when user stop sliding, so the other side updates accordigly.

Answer (score 5):

use the [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop) event

```
$sliderValue="";
$("#slider").slider({                   
                value: 50,
                min: 0,
                max: 99,
                step: 1,
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                                $("#slider_value").val(ui.value);
                          },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.value);
                $sliderValue=ui.value; //set the value to a global variable
            }
        });
        $("#slider_value").val($("#slider").slider("value"))

//send the value here
// $.post("http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY VALUE_FROM_SLIDER",{value:$sliderValue},function(data){...});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f2AWC/34/

Comment: great. the alert work as i update, $.post("http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY ",{value:$sliderValue};          is this correct?

Comment: how do you want to send the values vis `GET` or `POST` if you want to send it via querystring params you can do it like `http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY="+ui.value` also make sure whether the spaces are allowed within the query string parameters

Comment: going the post way, but it seems the it works, but only sends 1 update, if i slide it again,it doesnt send anything. thats ondomready. should i do this onLoad? how to call it to update on every slider change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f2AWC/38/ - this version works, stil i cant send more then one update on slider... enigma =) help!

Comment: i am not understanding what do you mean by cant send more than one update... can you please elaborate the scenario

Comment: if i move the slider, the value gets sent to the service, but if i move it again, it doesnt update the service anymore...

Comment: thanks ;) ill test it in a few days when i get back in the office ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the part with `http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY VALUE_FROM_SLIDER`. Can you elaborate a bit more there?

When you stop sliding, you can use `stop` function, which works the same way as `slide`. Documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop)

Comment: ok. ill explain a bit more. http is the code i send from html page to the sensor software. the html is the gui for it. i need to somehow implement a slider, since im changing values in software. thats why i need jquery to send it on stop sliding so the values in software are changing in sync.

Comment: http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY VALUE_FROM_SLIDER    name is a machine in the network i am sending request to, sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY is the channelset im sending too on sensor http socket, VALUE_FROM_SLIDER is the slider value user slided to. if the user slides to another value, slider updates the VALUE in the http string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the slider val and append it to the link href

e.g.

```
$('#link').attr('href','http://NAME/sensor?ConnectFloat InputB cf_GrA_l2pY '+$("#slider_value").val());
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Jayendra/f2AWC/32/

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late to answer on the post.
But after looking at the question.You might need to send an **AJAX request** over the **stop** event of the **jquery slider**.

Following code might be helpful in future for fellow programmers facing the same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider").slider({
            range : "min",
            min : 0,
            max : 100,
            value : 3,
            stop : function(event, ui) {                     
                slideValue = ui.value;
                       $.ajax({
                     url : "http://sample/url/request",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {
                        "slideValue" : slideValue
                    },
                                dataType : "json",
                         success : function(response){
                                         console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#toptions